# How to load local images from project directory in to the JS file

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Im facing an issue in my iOS app to load images from my project directory to JS file. When i load the JS file i get an icon with question mark[I use image tag to show image in my JS file]. The code which i have used to display image is as follows : . But it does not work. Is there any other ways to show images through JS file in iOS application.

Comment: 'The code which i have used to display image is as follows : . But it does not work.' I think you're missing some code.

Comment: <img src="../html/download.jpeg" width="32" height="32"/>

Comment: Are you sure the image exists at the location specified?

Comment: yes.. image exists there.. But it does not gets displayed

Comment: Also that's HTML, not JavaScript

Comment: that is the image tag i have used in my javascript to show the image as shown below:  lblBtn.innerHTML = sanitizeHTML('<a href="#" style="display: block; position: relative; padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px; margin: 3px 3px; border-radius: 4px; text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: #676767; border: 2px solid #676767; background-color: #ffffff; text-align:left; text-decoration: none;">' + getArrVal[i].nameq +'<img src="../html/download.jpeg" width="32" height="32"/></a>');

Comment: Right, could you please add all that to the question, would make it a lot clearer what you've done

Comment: i have made the changes

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to find the path of the images directly from the javaScript file. Because in simulator it works fine, whereas in iOS test device it does not works. So from the native find the path of the image as shown below and pass the path to the javaScript

```
NSString* filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"add_page" ofType:@"png"];

    NSString *imgHTMLTag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<img src=\"file://%@\" width=%@ height=%@/>", filePath12,@"32px",@"32px"];

    NSString * jsCallBackrr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myFunc('%@')",imgHTMLTag];

[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBackrr];
```

So i used this code to find the path and it works fine.... Happy coding ....

Answer (score 0):

quoted from: https://css-tricks.com/quick-reminder-about-file-paths/

> Here is all you need to know about relative file paths:
>
> Starting with "/" returns to the root directory and starts there
>   Starting with "../" moves one directory backwards and starts there
>   Starting with "../../" moves two directories backwards and starts
>   there (and so on...) To move forward, just start with the first
>   subdirectory and keep moving forward

Answer (score 0):

Try setting base URL like below :

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"index" withExtension:@"html"];
NSString *html = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```